# Problems with Xcode Source Control for Preexisting Project

Tags: iphone, ios, git, controls, version

So I have a project I created a year or so ago and I've been manually saving the files to an external hard drive every new version. With Xcode 4.2, source control is now totally integrated into Xcode. Or so I thought. The problem I have in not creating the `git` repo (see below) but getting it to work with Version Control.

In my directory (`cd` in) I did the following to create a git repository. I see it as such in the Organizer in Xcode and in Github for Mac. It truly is a git repo.

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m 'First commit'
```

But in Xcode, when I change a file, there is no `M` or `A` badge or otherwise that appears to let me know it's been changed. What's more, the source control contextual menu items are all disabled and thus entirely useless. I don't want to have to commit or revert in the Organizer or command line every time.

How do I enable this part of version control in Xcode? Some tag I add to the .xcodeproj file? A bool somewhere? A setting somewhere? Anyone know? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I figured out the problem. I had to clean the project before it would show me the badges. I restarted Xcode after that as well, which may or may not have helped. In any case, after that, it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I have also found a new clean linked repo to be the answer. Simply drag the whole folder containing the xcode proj file into the Git workspace and follow the prompts. After that all is linked and cool. That said I am aware that there may be more elegant solutions and answers.